# How to loop through datatable values without using for or foreach loop and then list values add to List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, generic-list

Tables[1] having list of values.

```
if (ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // How to loop through datatable values without using for or foreach loop and then list values add to List?//


   testRetrieveResponse.testList.Add();- how to add values to list 

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `foreach`?

Comment: what parameter to Add?

Comment: testList= new FacilityInfo();
                                testList.FacilityId = Convert.ToInt32(row["FACILITY_ID"]);
                                testList.FacilityName = Convert.ToString(row["FACILITY"]);
                                testRetrieveResponse.testList.Add(testList);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DataTable.AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<DataRow> list = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

OR, if you want to create list of some Type then you can use Select and make objects of your type.

```
List<DataRow> list = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(a => new YourType { Prop1 = a.Field<string>("Prop1")}).ToList();
```

Comment: I guess OP is looking for `List<T>` Where T is any custom object.

Comment: Probably, select could be used for that.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to [`Enumerable.Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) each element to [`DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx), then project the new element type with [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var customTypes = ds.Tables[1]
                    .Rows
                    .Cast<DataRow>()
                    .Select(row => new SomeType { Id = row["Id"] })
                    .ToList();
```